# Lua shared upvalue example in C

Tags: c, lua, closures, global-variables

Let's create a simple C module for *Lua 5.3* with a global `int`:

```
static int l_test(lua_State *L){
    int Global = lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    Global++;
    lua_pushinteger(L, Global);
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_replace(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    //lua_pushnumber(L, Global);
    return 1;
}

static int l_anotherTest(lua_State *L){
    int Global = lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    Global++;
    Global++;
    lua_pushinteger(L, Global);
    lua_pushvalue(L, -1);
    lua_replace(L, lua_upvalueindex(1));
    //lua_pushnumber(L, Global);
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg testLib [] = {
    {"test", l_test},
    {"anotherTest", l_anotherTest},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_testLib(lua_State *L){
    luaL_newlibtable(L, testLib);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 1);
    luaL_setfuncs(L, testLib, 1) ;    
    return 1;
}
```

This almost works, but when I call these two function from Lua like this:

```
local testLib = require "testLib"
print(testLib.test())
print(testLib.anotherTest())
```

The second print should be `4`, but it prints out a `3`.
What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: To initialize the upvalue, you should push its initial value onto the stack just before invoking `setfuncs`.  To access the upvalue from `l_test` you should use `lua_upvalueindex(1)` to get the stack pseudoindex where this value is located.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I've updated the question. There's still something missing here. Can you help me?

Comment: Use the `NULL` macro if you want a null pointer constant. Using the integer `0` is a missleading legacy.

Comment: Updated, olaf. But this does not take us further. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upvalues of C closures are not shared, only upvalues of Lua closures are. Every C closure contains its upvalues directly (see [here](https://www.lua.org/source/5.3/lobject.h.html#CClosure)). If you want to have shared values for two or more C closures, use a single common table as an upvalue in all of them and put your shared values in there, or use the registry for your shared data instead.

Something like the following should do what you want:

```
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>


/* getint and setint may only be called from Lua C functions that
 * have the shared table as upvalue 1.
 */

static int getint(lua_State *L){
  int v = 0;
  lua_getfield(L, lua_upvalueindex(1), "myint");
  v = lua_tointeger(L, -1);
  lua_pop(L, 1); /* remove integer from stack */
  return v;
}

static void setint(lua_State *L, int v){
  lua_pushinteger(L, v);
  lua_setfield(L, lua_upvalueindex(1), "myint");
}


static int l_test(lua_State *L){
    int Global = getint(L);
    Global++;
    setint(L, Global);
    lua_pushinteger(L, Global);
    return 1;
}

static int l_anotherTest(lua_State *L){
    int Global = getint(L);
    Global++;
    Global++;
    setint(L, Global);
    lua_pushinteger(L, Global);
    return 1;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg testLib [] = {
    {"test", l_test},
    {"anotherTest", l_anotherTest},
    {NULL, NULL}
};

int luaopen_testLib(lua_State *L){
    luaL_newlibtable(L, testLib);
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_pushinteger(L, 1);
    lua_setfield(L, -2, "myint");
    luaL_setfuncs(L, testLib, 1);
   return 1;
}
```

Comment: @siffiejoe - `luaL_setfuncs` allows you to SHARE upvalues among all the registering C functions. This is what OP tries to achieve.

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff: All C closures from the `luaL_setfuncs` call will have the same upvalues afterwards, but those upvalues are **not** shared, i.e. changing the upvalues of one closure has no effect on the upvalues of the other closures, *except* if you mutate values that are passed by reference like tables, userdata, etc. (all closures will have separate references to the same table/userdata/...).

Comment: I've dug out an old mailing list thread for you: http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2006-08/msg00189.html

Comment: @siffiejoe - Thanks.

Comment: @siffiejoe: This works perfectly! Thanks. Why -2 in `lua_setfield(L, -2, "myint");` though? For fieldname "myint" *and* its value?

Comment: @user1511417: The `-2` is a relative stack index and the target of the `lua_setfield` call. `-1` is the stack top (the integer in this case because it was pushed last), and `-2` (one below the stack top) is the table that was created before pushing the integer.